# Google Chrome Extension Hello World

Tags: google-chrome

I am going through the "Hello World" example on the Chrome dev pages (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html).

One thing I would like to do is to be able to grab the current selected tabs location.href and document.title.

For example if I am on www.apple.com and click the popup toolbar button I'm not sure how to access the www.apple.com document.

Comment: This is not jeopardy. Please state your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what "parts" of the extension?

E.g. An extension's "background page"?
  The "[tab](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html)" object contain the "url" (`location.href` in DOM terms ) parameter.

You'll have to communication between a "content script" and the background page. Once you have a communication channel, you can grab the tab_id and refer to #1 above.

---

You can always grab the current window/tab: have a look [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html). You can grab the tab_id.url from thereon.

Comment: Exactly. I guess I'm looking for the background page when in the context of a popup
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "toolbarButton.png",
    "popup": "popup.html"
  }

Thanks for the response. I will see what I can find for communicating to that background page.

Comment: it's a simple question, just change something in the main page.
All hello worlds on google talk about how to display something in a popup...